# Redirect to page if iFrame url is google.com

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I want to use javascript, so if an iframe on my page's url became 'https://google.com.eg' it must do a function

Function for example:

- Redirect to error.php using "window.href"
- Show javascript box saying "error"

My iframe is:

`<iframe src="https://translate.google.com.eg" id="myframe"></iframe>`

And I want to prevent my site visitors to go to the Google homepage.

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you need to prevent a user from exiting your site?

Comment: @zer00ne - please read my question carefully.

Comment: >And I want to prevent my site visitors to go to the Google homepage.< So I asked why? No need to reply, I'm no longer interested thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jquery 
   $(document).ready(function (){
    `var a = $('#myiframe').attr('src');`
    If(a == 'www.google.com' || a=='google.com' || a=='https://google.com.eg’){
    window.location.href="error.php";
    }
    });

Comment: Thank you, it seems jQuery will be more better than detecting DOM changes. I'm on mobile currently and I will test that once I'm on PC.

Answer (score 0):

In the iframe on load function check if document.getElementById("myiframe").contentWindow.location.href == "google.com" then proceed with your callback